# Phalcon DI phpStorm IDE not understand my code

Tags: php, dependency-injection, phalcon

I'm using phalcon in a new project but i realized that phpStorm is not  understanding my own injectors, for example:

```
   /**
     * Registering the helper component
     */
    $di->set('helper', function () {
        $helper = new \Frontend\Helpers\Common();
        return $helper;
    });
```

from my controller i can do that:

```
   $this->helper->getHelp();
```

and it is working fine, but the IDE do not autocomplete my code. Of course i could do that:

```
   /** @var \Frontend\Helpers\Common $helper  */
   $helper->...
```

In this case i can see all methods, but then each time when i need to use the helper i have to put this comments.

I would like to know if there is a way to use owns injectors and make the IDE abble to understand the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this workaround.

**services.php**

```
/**
 * Registering the helper component
 */
$di->set('helper', function () {
    $helper = new \Frontend\Helpers\Common();
    return $helper;
});
```

**AbstractController**

```
/**
 * My Abstract controller
 *
 * @property \Frontend\Helpers\Common helper
 */.
class AbstractController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{

}
```

**TestController**

```
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->helper->...
    }
}
```